# Undefined reference error for one specific library function

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-reference

I'm writing software to control a bladeRF radio card but I'm running into a strange compiler/linker error that I haven't been able to figure out. My code uses several functions and data structures defined in the library, libbladeRF, but for some reason I can't reference to one specific function.

However, if I modify the call with an improper argument type, g++ will throw an error to let me know that it doesn't conform to the definition, which seems to tell me that the linker *is* actually able to locate the reference.

What am I missing?

**Initial error:**

```
$ g++ bladeRF_test.cpp -o bladeRF_test -lbladeRF
/tmp/ccTWZzdJ.o: In function `enable_xb300()':
bladeRF_test.cpp:(.text+0x36a): undefined reference to `bladerf_xb300_set_amplifier_enable'
```

**Code excerpt:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <libbladeRF.h>
using namespace std;

...

int set_xb300_pa(bool enable) {
    bladerf_xb300_amplifier amp = BLADERF_XB300_AMP_PA;
    if ( bladerf_xb300_set_amplifier_enable(dev, amp, enable) ) {
        // Print error message
        return -1;
    } else {
        // Print success message
        return 0;
    }
}

...
```

**Function arguments changed from `(dev, amp, enable)` to `(&dev, amp, enable)`:**

```
$ g++ blade_hello.cpp -o blade_hello -lbladeRF
blade_hello.cpp: In function ‘int set_xb300_pa()’:
blade_hello.cpp:62:59: error: cannot convert ‘bladerf**’ to ‘bladerf*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int bladerf_xb300_set_amplifier_enable(bladerf*, bladerf_xb300_amplifier, bool)
                                                       ^
In file included from blade_hello.cpp:4:0:
/usr/local/include/libbladeRF.h:2226:15: note: declared here
int CALL_CONV bladerf_xb300_set_amplifier_enable(struct bladerf *dev,
           ^
```

Comment: Likely a missing `extern "C"`.

Comment: How `dev` is defined?

Comment: By changing the func call (from `dev` to `&dev`), you now get a __compiler__ error which happens sooner than the  __linker__ error you got in the 1st place. Try: `nm -S libbladeRF.so | grep bladerf_xb300_set_amplifier_enable` and see the output (it's not 100% reliable). Is the function meant to be called (defined by _libbladeRF.h_) or you wrote its signature yourself? Do the _.h_ and the _.so_ file belong to the same library (in terms of version)? If everything is alright, then I subscribe to the 1st comment.

Comment: Thanks, everybody! I was able to solve the problem. I tried adding an extern statement to no avail. Thanks for the `nm` tip, CristiFati; I wasn't aware of that tool before. I'm still a little hazy on the specifics but the issue wound up being solved with by specifying the location of the shared library to g++, e.g. `-L/usr/local/lib`. For some reason there is another library .so file with the same name located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. `nm`ing that library returns a `no symbols` response. Weird, but it works now.